# InstallScript: ChangeDirectory() call fails only in SILENTMODE

Tags: installshield, installscript

I have the following test [InstallScript](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/mergedProjects/installshield16langref/LangrefHome.htm) InstallShield code, which executes correctly in the normal interactive mode, but crashes `setup.exe /s` (silent) mode on calls to [ChangeDirectory](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/mergedProjects/installshield16langref/LangrefChangeDirectory.htm) that involve any sort of actual depth of directories.

```
//Note: "C:" ^ "temp" resolves to "C:\temp", but it never successfully 
//executes when run silent mode. It works fine in interactive mode, however.
ChangeDirectory("C:" ^ "temp");
//No subsequent code gets executed at this point in silent mode
```

I'm running this on a Windows 2008 x64 Server in a command window with Administrator privileges. The `c:\temp` directory exists, and `EVERYONE` has been granted full control rights to it.

The exit code is `-2147213312`, which is `0x80042000` in the [error guide](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/InstallScriptSetup-ExeErrors.htm) corresponding to

> The installation exited with the abort keyword because the end user
>   canceled the installation.

What could possibly be going on here? I've tried using the `try/catch` syntax to examine the error, but the catch block never executes in this case, seemingly asserting that there's no error but instead an `abort` called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Installscript Engine does a lot of stuff behind the scene. It keeps changing the working directory. Thus, it is not very reliable to use ChangeDirectory(). It is surely better to use FULL PATH to all executables and other files. LaunchAppAndWait() too has this trouble. So full path needs to be used without fail.

Further, the Installshield help for ChangeDirectory() clearly mentions the following:

> When you are specifying a file in your script, always specify the full
>   path (using the appropriate InstallShield system variable, for
>   example, SRCDIR) rather than depend on the current folder having the
>   appropriate value. The script internally executes code that can change
>   the current folder, so its value may not be what you expect.

The thing is, results are not reliable. They may work or may not.

Comment: Yes, this is what I had ended up doing to work around it, although it wasn't my original code that was using `ChangeDirectory()` - I was just tasked with making an installer work in silent mode that hadn't prior.

Answer (score 0):

We get this errorcode when our recorded .iss file is missing an entry in the .iss response file.

See [Creating the Response File](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/CreatetheResponseFile.htm) for more Details.

Logging an installscript setup didn't give us much information, so we wrote some functions to write to a custom logfile which helped us a lot.

Comment: That error code is generic, though, and doesn't really necessarily relate to my problem. My final solution was to just use explicit paths when doing I/O to avoid calling ChangeDirectory(), even if it works fine in the normal interactive mode. Sucks, but what are you going to do?